# Rearrange the order of the split strings and put into variables

Tags: c++, variables, split

I have a text file that has an http request from 3 domains (1st part is from reddit.com, 2nd is from stackoverflow.com, last is from google.com). My task is to rearrange the order of the http request inside of the txt file. For example, the order will become, google will be in the first, next is the reddit and stackoverflow will be the last data inside of the txt file.

My idea is to open the file using CreateFile function and read the content using ReadFile function. Then I will split the strings by using the delimiter "------". Then put the 3 split string inside of 3 variables in order to manipulate the data.

Is my idea possible or there are other ways to solve this? **also how to put the 3 split strings into 3 variables**?

thank you in advance!

Inside of a text file

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Retry-After: 0
Location: https://www.reddit.com/
Content-Length: 0
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 01:47:39 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-pao17440-PAO
X-Cache: HIT
X-Cache-Hits: 0k
X-Timer: S1542592059.341058,VS0,VE0
Cache-Control: private, max-age=3600
Server: snooserv

----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Location: https://stackoverflow.com/
Content-Length: 149
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 01:47:41 GMT
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Served-By: cache-pao17443-PAO
X-Cache: MISS
X-Cache-Hits: 0
X-Timer: S1542592061.319674,VS0,VE69
Vary: Fastly-SSL
X-DNS-Prefetch-Control: off
Set-Cookie: prov=27060b9e-21ce-fcb4-5b43-bf2f40747e6c;        domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

<head><title>Document Moved</title></head>
<body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This document may be found <a      HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/">here</a></body>
----------------------------------------
HTTP/1.0 411 Length Required
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Content-Length: 1564
Date: Mon, 19 Nov 2018 01:47:48 GMT

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 411 (Length Required)!!1</title>
  <style>
```

Comment: `std::array<std::vector<std::string>,3>` -- start with that.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of my common functions that I use when reading in data from a file along with a custom function for parsing that particular data type or set. Some of the functions are not used here directly in this example, but I provide them anyways since these are the 3 common ways of retrieving data from a file as well as two different ways of creating a set of tokens from a long string.

```
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>

// A basic method to split a string based on a single char delimiter
std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& s, char delimiter ) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    std::string token;
    std::istringstream tokenStream( s );
    while( std::getline( tokenStream, token, delimiter ) ) {
        tokens.push_back( token );
    }    
    return tokens;
}

// Similar to above but with the ability to use a string as a delimiter as opposed to just a single char
std::vector<std::string> splitString( const std::string& strStringToSplit, const std::string& strDelimiter, const bool keepEmpty = true ) {
    std::vector<std::string> tokens;
    if( strDelimiter.empty() ) {
        tokens.push_back( strStringToSplit );
        return tokens;
    }

    std::string::const_iterator itSubStrStart = strStringToSplit.begin(), itSubStrEnd;
    while( true ) {
        itSubStrEnd = search( itSubStrStart, strStringToSplit.end(), strDelimiter.begin(), strDelimiter.end() );
        std::string strTemp( itSubStrStart, itSubStrEnd );
        if( keepEmpty || !strTemp.empty() ) {
            tokens.push_back( strTemp );
        }

        if( itSubStrEnd == strStringToSplit.end() ) {
            break;
        }
        itSubStrStart = itSubStrEnd + strDelimiter.size();
    }
    return tokens;
}

// This function will open a file, read a single line
// closes the file handle and returns that line as a std::string
std::string getLineFromFile( const char* filename ) {
    std::ifstream file( filename );
    if( !file ) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "failed to open file " << filename << '\n';
        throw std::runtime_error( stream.str() );
    }

    std::string line;
    std::getline( file, line );

    file.close();

    return line;
}

// This function will open a file and read the file line by line
// storing each line as a string and closes the file then returns
// the contents as a std::vector<std::string>
void getAllLinesFromFile( const char* filename, std::vector<std::string>& output ) {
    std::ifstream file( filename );
    if( !file ) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "failed to open file " << filename << '\n';
        throw std::runtime_error( stream.str() );
    }

    std::string line;
    while( std::getline( file, line ) ) {
        if( line.size() > 0 )
            output.push_back( line );
    }

    file.close();
}

// This function will open a file and read all of the file's contents and store it into
// a large buffer or a single string and returns that as its output.
void getDataFromFile( const char* filename, std::string& output ) {
    std::ifstream file( filename );
    if( !file ) {
        std::stringstream stream;
        stream << "failed to open file " << filename << '\n';
        throw std::runtime_error( stream.str() );
    }

    std::stringstream buf;
    buf << file.rdbuf();
    output.clear();
    output.reserve( buf.str().length() );
    output = buf.str();
}

// A function to parse the data based on your data types or data sets
// and the criteria that is needed for its layout, format etc. 
void parseDataFromFile( const std::string& fileContents, std::vector<std::string>& output ) {
    std::string delimiter( "----------------------------------------" );
    output = splitString( fileContents, delimiter );

    // More parsing may need to be done here, but this would be according
    // to your specific needs and what you intend to do from this point on.
}

int main() {
    try {
        std::string fileContents;
        getDataFromFile( "test.txt", fileContents );
        std::vector<std::string> tokens;
        parseDataFromFile( fileContents, tokens );

        // This is just temp code to display the file as
        // a vector of strings that were split by your delimiter
        // This is where you would reorder your data and rewrite it
        // back to some file, log, stream, cout, etc. 
        std::cout << "First Token:\n\n";
        for( auto& s : tokens ) {
            if( s != tokens.back() )
                std::cout << s << "\n\nNext Token:\n";
            else
                std::cout << s << '\n';
        }

    } catch( std::runtime_error& e ) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As you can see from the output that this program generates I have successfully shown how to split a string based on the type of delimiter that your situation requires. From here all you need to do is sort the data based on your criteria. Then log your contents either to a stream, the console or another file.